# How to find the angle between two lines?

Tags: vectors

I was trying to figure out a question from the Vectors chapter, which goes as following:

> The line $L_1$ has equation $\frac{x-2}{2}=\frac{y+3}{3}=1-z$. The line $L_2$ meets line $L_1$ on the X-axis and passes through (5, -3, 1). Find the angle between the lines.

I attempted the question as follows:
$$L_1:\frac{x-2}{2}=\frac{y+3}{3}=1-z$$
$\implies <2, 3, -1>$ is the direction vector of $L_1$.

Also, if line $L_1$ passes through the X-axis, $\implies y=0, z=0$,
$$\therefore 2+2\lambda=0, 3\lambda-3=0$$
$$\implies \lambda=1$$
$$\therefore x=4$$
This means that line $L_1$ and line $L_2$ intersect on the point (4, 0, 0).
Therefore, the direction vector of line $L_2$ is as follows:
$$<1, -3, 1>$$
$$\therefore \theta=cos^{-1}(\frac{|<2, 3, -1>\cdot<1, -3, 1>|}{|<2, 3, -1>||<1, -3, 1>|})$$
$$\implies \theta=49.9^o$$
However, the answer to the question is $68.8^o$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've got the same value